# Pushing boolean value at a specific index in an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to push a Boolean value at a specific index in an array. Whenever I  ran the code I get this error, **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

This is my code:

```
              var check_ins = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < this.employees.length; i++) {
            // let check = check_ins[i];
            if (check_ins[i] === true) {
              let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Sorry,',
                subTitle: 'ur already checked in',
                buttons: ['OK']
              });
              alert.present();
              break;
            } else if (check_ins[i] === false || check_ins[i] === undefined) {
              let checkInTime = new TimeInModel(in_timing.date, emp_id, in_timing.time_in);
              this.employeesService.pushTimeIn(checkInTime)
                .subscribe(checkInTime => {
                },
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
              console.log("Successfully checked-in!");
              check_ins[i].push(true);
              break;
            }
```

What could be the problem? Is there another alternative to using an array to achieve the same output?

Comment: The way you are doing `push` is wrong. It has to be `check_ins.push(true);`

Comment: `check_ins[i] === undefined` so you cannot call a function on it. Also, `check_ins[i]` is, when a value is present, a boolean value. You cannot use the function `push` on a boolean. You need to use `check_ins.push(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push the value `true` into `check_ins[i]`, you can just set it: `check_ins[i] = true` or push true to the array: `check_ins.push(true)`

Answer (score 0):

When you use push, the pushed value gets added as a new element to the array. I suggest you do the following instead :

```
   var check_ins = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.employees.length; i++) {
        // let check = check_ins[i];
        if (check_ins[i] === true) {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Sorry,',
            subTitle: 'ur already checked in',
            buttons: ['OK']
          });
          alert.present();
          break;
        } else if (check_ins[i] === false || check_ins[i] === undefined) {
          let checkInTime = new TimeInModel(in_timing.date, emp_id, in_timing.time_in, true);
          this.employeesService.pushTimeIn(checkInTime)
            .subscribe(checkInTime => {
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
          console.log("Successfully checked-in!");
          check_ins[i]=true;
          break;
        }
```

Comment: That partly solved my problem. It's like the value "true" has not been saved anywhere because am able to do check-in twice on the same employee.

Picture this, after first check-in the status for the given id should be set to true therefore the second time the alert message should pop up saying already checked in @Abhay Naveen

Comment: @7guyo, aren't you supposed to changed the status for the employee when you set check_in[i] status as true? as long as the page is not refreshed the values will be saved and unaltered.